# WPF CustomControl stops showing up 50% of the time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom control in my WPF project, I've defined the style, the class, and I've called it in my xaml and made sure to include a reference. when I start the project 50% of the time the custom object renders perfectly, the other 50% it just doesn't show up, but is still interactable.

```
    public class PermissionBox : Control
{
    public PermissionBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(PermissionBox);
    }
    public string PumpID
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(PumpIDProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PumpIDProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PumpIDProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PumpID", typeof(string), typeof(PermissionBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


    public string FuelType
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(FuelTypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(FuelTypeProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FuelTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FuelType", typeof(string), typeof(PermissionBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
}
```

in Themes/Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:POS">


<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:PermissionBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:PermissionBox}">
                <Grid Background="Gray" Opacity="0.8">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" Text="Pump ID:" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" Text="{TemplateBinding PumpID}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" Text="Fuel Type:" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" Text="{TemplateBinding FuelType}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and the calling window

```
    <Window x:Class="POS.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:POS"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
    <controls:PermissionBox PumpID="100" FuelType="Unleaded">        </controls:PermissionBox>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Really appreciate any help with resolving this.

Comment: Is that really the entire XAML for the window? What kind of interaction does the control have?

Comment: There is a another window is the actual UI but I thought if the custom object doesnt work in an empty window why would it work better in the actual main window? regardless the object doesnt work in the mainwindow either :). Just wanted to show how I'm calling it incase I made a mistake

Comment: If it fails to appear in the XAML you showed in the question, that's fine. When you say "it just doesn't show up, but is still interactable", I cannot guess what you are describing. Can you explain in specific, concrete detail exactly what it means for a read-only control to be "still interactable"? Is the gray rectangle there with no text?

Comment: No text no Gray rectangle, not visible at all, but still interactable in the design view and in the MainWindow there is an onClick event that just hits a breakpoint for now which still triggers correctly

Comment: But half of the time, you see a gray window with superimposed bold text?

Comment: Is there any pattern? You hit F5 ten times, five times you get an empty window, five times you get the TextBlocks on top of each other?

Comment: Yep, half the time the gray window shows up perfectly with the right labels and the right pumpID and Fueltype :/

Comment: I can't reproduce it. There's something you're leaving out. An empty control that responds to clicks would be consistent with the style not being in scope, thus not applying the control template. Is there anything clever about how resources are included? In my test I just merged the resource dictionary in App.xaml.

Comment: By reproduce it do you mean it wont show up at all or that it consistently shows up? The resource dictionary is in a xaml file called Generix.xaml within a folder Themes. Another post on here claimed that the exact naming of that folder was necessary :S

Comment: Shows up every time. I just moved the resource file to Themes\Generic.xaml and took the merge out of App.xaml and it's working fine. I can break it by commenting out `DefaultStyleKey = typeof(PermissionBox);` in the static constructor.

Comment: Could you possibly show me the App.xaml and the App.xaml.cs, since I guess that's the only difference

Comment: Those are just the empty defaults now.

Comment: And you're not adding anything extra to the invocation? just the pumpID and the Fueltype? I don't give mine a size or anything is all but it doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: I copied and pasted your XAML verbatim.

Comment: Well....I guess a clean solution is just what I'm going to have to try, thank you.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. Then you can work backward to it by process of un-elimination.